# AWS SES Email Receiving SDK for Spring Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-simple-email-service

We have a Spring Boot application, that's required to listen to incoming emails from AWS SES, retrieve the email and persist it to the database. I've come across documentation to send out the email from Java, but I couldn't find any specific documentation to listen to an email from the application via SES and get the latest reply.

Currently I am using S3 as the storage and planning to write integration with SNS to listen and read from S3 whenever an email has come using Spring Cloud.

Is there any much better alternative to this method, where I can just let the application listen to the reply to the email that was sent?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this method:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ses/SesClient.html#getSendStatistics--

See if that method provides information that you can use.

Comment: This is actually completely incorrect. AWS SES can readily receive emails that can be used as part of application pipelines, and much more.